# Dynamic re-sizing of images according to the sizes(Same width but different height)

Tags: android, image-scaling

I would like to dynamically resize my images taken from camera in android. I want an output like the pinterest images.

[image]

Comment: Will this link solve my issues ? (https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridViewDemo
https://github.com/jacobmoncur/QuiltViewLibrary)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the ImageView's width to your custom size, its height to wrap_content and the important thing is to set the ImageView's scaleType to fitXY

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/yourImage1"/>    

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/yourImage2"/>    

</LinearLayout>
```